# What is faster for or each?

Tags: jquery, ajax, optimization, for-loop, each

I have an AJAX + jQuery example, where on success I have my data array. For my experiment in Firebug, I didn't see much difference. Which is faster, `for` or `each` in jQuery?

`for` example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + data[i].c_id + '">'+ data[i].c_name +'</option>';
}
```

`each` example:

```
$(data).each(function() {
    options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('c_id') + '">' + $(this).attr('c_name') + '</option>';
});
```

Comment: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/192

Comment: awesome, thanks, can you repost it like answer

Comment: If you can't see any difference, go with what's more legible or easier to maintain. It's not worth sacrificing them for a theoretical speed boost that makes no practical difference.

Comment: i try `for (var i in data)` and i think it's faster, but i'm not sure.

Comment: @Stopper - Thats the slowest. Check the jsperf text above.

Comment: yes, i see, for loop with caching is faster

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case for loop would definetly be faster. You would generally prefer using the .each() of jquery when iterating over the html tags in your page.
Jquery may not always be faster than core javasript, but its definetly much more cleaner and developer friendly ;)

Answer (score 2):

definitely for loop is faster. but there will be very small difference. it only make difference if you have very large data.